# application error when trying to Deploy static website with bootstrap template to heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy a single page `html/css/js` site that was built using a bootstrap template to Heroku and continue to get an application error. I've tried some of the hacks I've found online but continue to fail with

`npm ERR! missing script: start`

as well as, here is the most recent log. Can anyone help?

Comment: You missed adding the log contents to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the root of your files, file with name **Procfile**
and there add this line:

```
web: node [app.js]
```

or just add to your **package.json** file in the **scripts** this line:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node [app.js]"
}
```

where **app.js** is the server start file.